# How do I determine which boot partition is Windows 10 using

Tags: windows-10, boot-partition

This one takes a bit to explain:

Had one boot drive in Windows for years (Window 95->7->8->10) - Cloning to a bigger and better drive often. Switched over to an SSD and simply cloned the drive and made new drive C: and old drive D: and worked merrily. (A few years ago , like 2018). Using UEFI.

However, it now seems that the actual drive that does the booting is Drive D:! Every once in a while , after a Windows Update reboot, the OS does not boot and I get a BSOD. If I go to the BIOS and change the boot drive to another one (2 appear witch exact same Microsoft Boot Name), the system continues happily.

1. How do I determine which actual partition booted the system?
2. How do I mirror the GOOD partition to the Drive C: if it's actually Drive
   D: and make sure it boots from the C: boot partition
3. Can I actually rename a Windows UEFI name - safely is the key - so that the BIOS names give me a hint.
4. Can a drive have 2 UEFI boot partitions?

The big fear of course is to nuke the correct boot partition and be SOL and not be able to boot at all.

[image: UEFI Windows Boot Options]

EDIT:
Checking Disk Management - Weird 2 Recovery Partitions - I Don't see 2 EFI Partitions that the BIOS shows

[image]

Comment: You have 5 questions, hare at SU we ask that you only ask one for each post.

Comment: Please take a screenshot of the entire window of Disk Management and add it to your post.

Comment: Could "Windows Boot Manager" have 2 entries???

Answer (score 1):

1. This question was already answered 2 years ago [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1399789/how-do-i-find-out-which-efi-system-partition-is-in-use-by-windows-10).
2. Follow this guide [on how to mirror EFI partitions](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/mirror-boot-hard-drive-windows-10).
3. Follow this guide [on how to change the name](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/rename-or-change-os-name-in-windows-boot-manager).
4. Although Windows Installer doesn't like it, you can have several. It's not recommended, but yes.

Comment: VERY helpful. Thanks! Clarified my issue with the proper tools. I can't find 2 EFI partitions but my BIOS thinks so. But now I have an idea on how to proceed