How to restore a Windows Boot Loader entry (removed by installation of another OS) to my UEFI GUI (and GRUB2)?
Problem
I have an installation of Windows 11 (Build 27754, from the Canary channel) which was installed alongside a Fedora 41 KDE Spin installation (upgraded from F40, which it was installed as).
Recently, that F41 installation became unbootable (because an --offline dnf update did not correctly apply, rendering systemd-journald unable to invoke, outside the rescue kernel).
To remediate this:

I wrote Fedora-KDE-Live-x86_64-41-1.4.iso (from fedoraproject.org/spins/kde/download) to a SANDISK USB-A (presumably USB2.0) storage device, via FedoraMediaWriter-win64-5.1.3.exe.

I replaced that F41 installation with another Fedora 41 KDE Spin installation.
All disk management in Anaconda was entirely automatic. I merely selected the storage device and chose "I would like to make additional space available" and chose "Delete all" (partitions) when prompted to do so.


As this report of mine states, the F41 KDE Spin installation process (somehow) removed the Windows Boot Loader EFI entry from both my UEFI GUI and the new GRUB2 installation.
Requested Solution
This is the crux of this issue - I want to recreate my Windows 11 installation's bootloader entry. At the least, I want it to appear inside my ASRock X670E Taichi motherboard's UEFI GUI. Ideally, I want it to also inside my new F41's GRUB2 TUI, too.
Hypothesised Cause
I presume that the latter aforereferenced option in Anaconda (the installer GUI) removes the boot information for all installed OSes? I have concluded this because, from (yet uncited) searches, the consensus online is that boot information for all OSes should solely reside on one partition on one storage device.
This means that unless a separate storage device is designated solely for .EFI-file storage, all subsequent OS installations (even on separate storage devices) shall add their .EFI files to the boot partition of the first OS that was installed.
If my comprehension is correct, then this means that I deleted this partition, and that I should not have. Please confirm this.
Remediation Attempts

os-prober does not detect the Windows Boot Loader.

I am wary to adhere to youtu.be/CZ17JrgFFhw (and youtu.be/LILSaEGzhOg) because they do not deal with an absent EFI entry - rather, a malformed one. This means that the former's sanity check (running bcdedit at the start of the restoration process) is non-functional for me:

The boot configuration data store could not be opened.  
The system could not find the file specified.


I have 0% confidence that youtu.be/MIvuDTSGdbg isn't a fluke.


Environment (Storage Devices)

Hardware
If of note, both storage devices are SSDs connected via NVMe:



Name
M.2
Origin




Addlink A95
True
Amazon.co.UK


Samsung SSD 980 Pro
True
Amazon.co.UK



SMART
All storage devices in my hardware configuration, including the aforementioned, have perfect SMART records, according to the GUIs I have checked them with (KDE's partitionmanager, as an example):
smartctl 7.4 2023-08-01 r5530 [x86_64-linux-6.11.10-300.fc41.x86_64] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-23, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Number:                       Samsung SSD 980 PRO 250GB
Serial Number:                      S5GZNF0R106204B
Firmware Version:                   2B2QGXA7
PCI Vendor/Subsystem ID:            0x144d
IEEE OUI Identifier:                0x002538
Total NVM Capacity:                 250,059,350,016 [250 GB]
Unallocated NVM Capacity:           0
Controller ID:                      6
NVMe Version:                       1.3
Number of Namespaces:               1
Namespace 1 Size/Capacity:          250,059,350,016 [250 GB]
Namespace 1 Utilization:            141,146,243,072 [141 GB]
Namespace 1 Formatted LBA Size:     512
Namespace 1 IEEE EUI-64:            002538 b111b054a0
Local Time is:                      Sun Dec  1 19:56:30 2024 GMT
Firmware Updates (0x16):            3 Slots, no Reset required
Optional Admin Commands (0x0017):   Security Format Frmw_DL Self_Test
Optional NVM Commands (0x0057):     Comp Wr_Unc DS_Mngmt Sav/Sel_Feat Timestmp
Log Page Attributes (0x0f):         S/H_per_NS Cmd_Eff_Lg Ext_Get_Lg Telmtry_Lg
Maximum Data Transfer Size:         128 Pages
Warning  Comp. Temp. Threshold:     82 Celsius
Critical Comp. Temp. Threshold:     85 Celsius

Supported Power States
St Op     Max   Active     Idle   RL RT WL WT  Ent_Lat  Ex_Lat
 0 +     8.49W       -        -    0  0  0  0        0       0
 1 +     4.48W       -        -    1  1  1  1        0     200
 2 +     3.18W       -        -    2  2  2  2        0    1000
 3 -   0.0400W       -        -    3  3  3  3     2000    1200
 4 -   0.0050W       -        -    4  4  4  4      500    9500

Supported LBA Sizes (NSID 0x1)
Id Fmt  Data  Metadt  Rel_Perf
 0 +     512       0         0

=== START OF SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

SMART/Health Information (NVMe Log 0x02)
Critical Warning:                   0x00
Temperature:                        44 Celsius
Available Spare:                    100%
Available Spare Threshold:          10%
Percentage Used:                    10%
Data Units Read:                    29,241,658 [14.9 TB]
Data Units Written:                 85,878,151 [43.9 TB]
Host Read Commands:                 267,134,839
Host Write Commands:                1,101,319,506
Controller Busy Time:               5,926
Power Cycles:                       1,304
Power On Hours:                     1,206
Unsafe Shutdowns:                   197
Media and Data Integrity Errors:    0
Error Information Log Entries:      0
Warning  Comp. Temperature Time:    0
Critical Comp. Temperature Time:    0
Temperature Sensor 1:               44 Celsius
Temperature Sensor 2:               47 Celsius

Error Information (NVMe Log 0x01, 16 of 64 entries)
No Errors Logged

Read Self-test Log failed: Invalid Field in Command (0x002)

If you do not believe this, please provide me with commands to invoke to verify.

Software

tree of /boot/efi/EFI/
/boot/efi/EFI/
├── BOOT
│   ├── BOOTIA32.EFI
│   ├── BOOTX64.EFI
│   ├── fbia32.efi
│   └── fbx64.efi
└── fedora
    ├── BOOTIA32.CSV
    ├── BOOTX64.CSV
    ├── gcdia32.efi
    ├── gcdx64.efi
    ├── grub.cfg
    ├── grubia32.efi
    ├── grubx64.efi
    ├── mmia32.efi
    ├── mmx64.efi
    ├── shim.efi
    ├── shimia32.efi
    └── shimx64.efi

3 directories, 16 files


lsblk CLI
#!/usr/bin/env -S bash
sudo lsblk -o NAME,KNAME,MAJ:MIN,FSTYPE,MOUNTPOINT,LABEL,UUID,RO,RM,MODEL,SIZE,STATE,OWNER,GROUP,MODE,ALIGNMENT,MIN-IO,OPT-IO,PHY-SEC,LOG-SEC,ROTA,SCHED,RQ-SIZE,TYPE,DISC-ALN,DISC-GRAN,DISC-MAX,DISC-ZERO

I have painstakingly converted the output to a Markdown table:
NAME        | KNAME     | MAJ:MIN | FSTYPE | MOUNTPOINT | LABEL   | UUID                                 | RO | RM | MODEL                               | SIZE   | STATE   | OWNER | GROUP | MODE       | ALIGNMENT | MIN-IO | OPT-IO | PHY-SEC | LOG-SEC | ROTA  | SCHED | RQ-SIZE | TYPE | DISC-ALN | DISC-GRAN | DISC-MAX | DISC-ZERO
------------|-----------|---------|--------|------------|---------|--------------------------------------|----|----|-------------------------------------|--------|---------|-------|-------|------------|-----------|--------|--------|---------|---------|-------|-------|---------|------|----------|-----------|----------|----------
sda         | sda       |   8:0   |        |            |         |                                      | 0  | 1  | Flash Disk                          |  14.5G | running | root  | disk  | brw-rw---- |         0 |  512   |    0   |  512    |  512    | 1     | bfq   |       2 | disk |        0 |      512B |       0B |         0
└─sda1      | sda1      |   8:1   | vfat   |            | ESD-USB | C4E0-38AE                            | 0  | 1  |                                     |  14.5G |         | root  | disk  | brw-rw---- |         0 |  512   |    0   |  512    |  512    | 1     | bfq   |       2 | part |        0 |      512B |       0B |         0
sdb         | sdb       |   8:16  |        |            |         |                                      | 0  | 1  | MassStorageClass                    |     0B | running | root  | disk  | brw-rw---- |         0 |  512   |    0   |  512    |  512    | 0     | bfq   |       2 | disk |        0 |      512B |       0B |         0
sdc         | sdc       |   8:32  |        |            |         |                                      | 0  | 1  | MassStorageClass                    |     0B | running | root  | disk  | brw-rw---- |         0 |  512   |    0   |  512    |  512    | 0     | bfq   |       2 | disk |        0 |      512B |       0B |         0
zram0       | zram0     | 252:0   |        | [SWAP]     |         |                                      | 0  | 0  |                                     |     8G |         | root  | disk  | brw-rw---- |         0 | 4096   | 4096   | 4096    | 4096    | 0     |       |         | disk |        0 |        4K |       2T |         0
nvme0n1     | nvme0n1   | 259:0   |        |            |         |                                      | 0  | 0  | addlink M.2 PCIE G4x4 NVMe          |   1.8T | live    | root  | disk  | brw-rw---- |         0 |  512   |    0   |  512    |  512    | 0     | none  |    1023 | disk |        0 |      512B |       2T |         0
├─nvme0n1p1 | nvme0n1p1 | 259:2   | vfat   | /boot/efi  |         | 8C16-B16E                            | 0  | 0  |                                     |   600M |         | root  | disk  | brw-rw---- |         0 |  512   |    0   |  512    |  512    | 0     | none  |    1023 | part |        0 |      512B |       2T |         0
├─nvme0n1p2 | nvme0n1p2 | 259:3   | ext4   | /boot      |         | 84cfd3a5-f2a3-4a30-80e9-75885f086a17 | 0  | 0  |                                     |     1G |         | root  | disk  | brw-rw---- |         0 |  512   |    0   |  512    |  512    | 0     | none  |    1023 | part |        0 |      512B |       2T |         0
└─nvme0n1p3 | nvme0n1p3 | 259:4   | btrfs  | /home      | fedora  | e8f3f913-c9b3-4d02-9343-0b91e71950e0 | 0  | 0  |                                     |   1.8T |         | root  | disk  | brw-rw---- |         0 |  512   |    0   |  512    |  512    | 0     | none  |    1023 | part |        0 |      512B |       2T |         0
nvme1n1     | nvme1n1   | 259:1   |        |            |         |                                      | 0  | 0  | addlink M.2 PCIE G4x4 NVMe          |   1.8T | live    | root  | disk  | brw-rw---- |         0 |  512   |    0   |  512    |  512    | 0     | none  |    1023 | disk |        0 |      512B |       2T |         0
└─nvme1n1p1 | nvme1n1p1 | 259:5   | btrfs  |            | s11vzd  | a8dc8530-f314-407a-896c-861783f62ecf | 0  | 0  |                                     |   1.8T |         | root  | disk  | brw-rw---- |         0 |  512   |    0   |  512    |  512    | 0     | none  |    1023 | part |        0 |      512B |       2T |         0
nvme3n1     | nvme3n1   | 259:6   |        |            |         |                                      | 0  | 0  | SK hynix PC401 HFS256GD9TNG-62A0A   | 238.5G | live    | root  | disk  | brw-rw---- |         0 |  512   |    0   |  512    |  512    | 0     | none  |     511 | disk |        0 |      512B |       2T |         0
nvme2n1     | nvme2n1   | 259:7   |        |            |         |                                      | 0  | 0  | Samsung SSD 980 PRO 250GB           | 232.9G | live    | root  | disk  | brw-rw---- |         0 |  512   |    0   |  512    |  512    | 0     | none  |    1023 | disk |        0 |      512B |       2T |         0
├─nvme2n1p1 | nvme2n1p1 | 259:8   | btrfs  |            | s2ve9g  | 17c0335b-73c9-45b1-aabe-f62a6e633d98 | 0  | 0  |                                     |    16M |         | root  | disk  | brw-rw---- |         0 |  512   |    0   |  512    |  512    | 0     | none  |    1023 | part |        0 |      512B |       2T |         0
├─nvme2n1p2 | nvme2n1p2 | 259:9   | ntfs   |            |         | 182A50072A4FE07C                     | 0  | 0  |                                     | 232.1G |         | root  | disk  | brw-rw---- |         0 |  512   |    0   |  512    |  512    | 0     | none  |    1023 | part |        0 |      512B |       2T |         0
└─nvme2n1p3 | nvme2n1p3 | 259:10  | ntfs   |            |         | E8DA341BDA33E50A                     | 0  | 0  |                                     |   830M |         | root  | disk  | brw-rw---- |         0 |  512   |    0   |  512    |  512    | 0     | none  |    1023 | part |        0 |      512B |       2T |         0


KDE's partitionmanager GUI







Windows's diskpart (and bcdedit) CLIs
Inside the Media Creation Tool's embedded cmd.exe GUI, I can run diskpart.exe, which provides the undermentioned information:


I'll OCR this when I can, but I've used all my ChatGPT credits.





Your KDE Partition Manager screenshot shows the contents of only one NVMe disk out of four. Is that the disk which used to have Windows installed? What partitions still exist on all other disks?

@grawity, that's indeed the storage device which has Windows on it. I can take screenshots of all four storage devices, but do you know of a command whose output would more concisely communicate what those screenshots would depict?

Normally BootRec /RebuildBCDor BcdBoot C:\Windows /s Y: /f UEFI is used, however with dual booting Linux, bootrec will overwrite GRUB (unsure about bcdboot) - for dual booting Linux with Windows, there's a Linux program that replicates what bootrec does, however I forget the name, although harrymc has an answer on here somewhere listing the program name and steps.

@JW0914, I've tried to search for that answer or comment, but have been unsuccessful. His accounts are completely devoid of contact information too, and he's suspended. Do you think that the link to what you saw would be in your browser history? I ask only because otherwise, I don't think I'll ever find the tool.

Solely one of my drives appeared to have a Windows installation when I performed (the pseudocode) sel disk $number && list part, so I didn't need to differentiate Windows installations. However, diskpart wasn't displaying the hidden flag that most tutorials appear to rely upon.
Despite this, I estimated that detail part (or detail vol) would, so when I had ascertained which disk my Windows installation was on (in my case, disk 3), I performed:

sel disk 3
list part

In each partition, I then performed detail part. Lo and behold, my estimation was correct, for a subsequent list vol included the flags.
This was useful, because although I had previously been searching for a FAT32 partition (or volume) the hidden flag was solely applied to Fedora's FAT32 volume. For Windows, the hidden volume was NTFS.
Consequently, I assigned a letter with:

sel vol 2
assign letter="S"

Then, invoking the command provided by the previous answer — bcdboot C:\Windows /s S: /f UEFI — worked:

Boot files successfully created.

A mere reboot was enough for Windows Boot Manager to appear within my motherboard firmware's GUI.

superuser.com/revisions/1507645/3 is probably the most comprehensive source of information pertaining to this. However, most of its steps are inapplicable except for the most damaged installations.

The EFI boot entry itself contains very little information besides the name: just a partition GUID (pointing to the "EFI System Partition") and a file path within that partition. It can contain "extra arguments" for the loader, but the Windows Boot Manager starts fine without them.
So if the file is still present – for Windows it's the \EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi file – then the entry can be re-added using efibootmgr from Linux. (Boot entry paths are relative to the root of the partition, so this would be /boot/efi/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi from the Fedora perspective.)
efibootmgr -c -l '\EFI\foobar' -L "Windows"

The important part is that you likely have also deleted the actual files that were in the previous EFI System Partition. To restore them (and to build a new BCD file that contained the actual configuration for Windows Boot Manager), you'll need to boot into any Windows installation DVD or USB stick and use bcdboot.exe to reinstall the boot manager.

open Cmd;

find the volume that corresponds to your EFI System Partition, and assign it a temporary drive letter if it doesn't have one (S: in this example);

find the volume that contains your \Windows directory;

reinstall the Windows Boot Manager using:
bcdboot C:\Windows /s S: /f UEFI



This will copy originals from \Windows\Boot, build a new configuration, and create the EFI boot entry (by default giving it higher priority than the "Fedora GRUB" entry).
Note that you can have a separate EFI System Partition for each physical drive – it is not limited to one per system. So it might make sense to create a separate ESP on the disk containing Windows and install the Windows Boot Manager into that instead.
(In rare cases even multiple ESPs per drive can be used; the UEFI specification doesn't outright forbid that, since boot entries reference it by GUID and not merely by type, although it's not very useful.)

Meanwhile, the GRUB2 menu has no relationship with the UEFI menu – adding entries to GRUB2 is a completely separate issue.
Usually, detecting Windows is the job of os-prober during grub-mkconfig. It should do this automatically after the boot manager is installed via bcdboot.

I know bootrec will overwrite GRUB, will bcdboot?

It won't. I've never used bootrec, but the name reminds me of an old Windows XP-era tool and frankly "overwriting GRUB" sounds a lot like an MBR-era issue... But as far as I've used bcdboot on dual-boot UEFI systems (and systems with other misc junk in the ESP), I'm sure that it does not delete any files outside of \EFI\Microsoft, and it does not remove other EFI boot entries either (although it inserts the new entry as 1st in the list).

bootrec is the normal boot recovery program in WinRE to fix all Windows boot issues, however it does overwrite GRUB AFAIK on GPT drives as well (a Linux program exists that replicates what bootrec does when dual-booting Linux, which won't overwrite GRUB, however I forget the name - issue with bootrec is it lacks functionality to know there might be other bootloaders and overwrites where GRUB is stored).

Yeah, that definitely sounds like an MBR-era issue, and I'd really expect both of those tools to write a clean Windows MBR bootsector over the GRUB bootsector (and related to that, overwriting the GRUB kernel image that installs in the "post-MBR" gap on BIOS systems is easy to do even by accident, too). But in the case of EFI it wouldn't need to know where other bootloaders might be in order to avoid them – after all, the filesystem already keeps track of that – so if it somehow deleted e.g. \EFI\grub\*.efi then that would need to be pretty deliberate.

(There's a Linux tool ms-sys that writes MBR bootsectors and FAT/NTFS VBRs, but it doesn't generate the BCD config for Bootmgr; it's useful for making hand-made Windows USB sticks bootable though.)

Thanks for clarifying that it shan't bork GRUB, @grawity.

@grawity, I have a bootmgfw.efi file at file:///run/media/$USER/182A50072A4FE07C/Windows/Boot/EFI/bootmgfw.efi (alongside a lot of backups, as as imgur.com/dulPiUF demonstrates). Is the full path what I should use for efibootmgr -c -l, or should I use the relative path - /Windows/Boot/EFI/bootmgfw.efi? I ask because I see that you started the parameter's value in your example with \EFI despite it being in \Windows\EFI, so I'd like to confirm.

@grawity, I've also added the output of tree /boot/efi/EFI/ to my question at /revisions/1863343/8. However, there's no bootmgfw.efi file in there, so do I need to copy the aforereferenced file into that directory before invoking efibootmgr?


You're looking at the wrong partition. The files within \Windows\Boot are not the "EFI System Partition" files – the EFI System Partition is practically never NTFS – instead they're the "original" files distributed as part of the OS image, that bcdboot would copy into the actual EFI System Partition (into \EFI\Microsoft) as part of the installation. 2) Don't copy them manually; you'll still need the BCD configuration file to be generated anyway. Use the bcdboot tool.


@grawity, apologies for that. I realized I'd better read some of the documentation myself to get more confident, so I did, understood the command you'd provided, then booted using the installation media. Unfortunately, no matter how much I searched, I seemed to only be able to find the Fedora boot volume, containing EFI, System, and mach_kernel directories. EFI contained solely BOOT and Fedora - no Microsoft. The sole other FAT32 volume was the ESD-USB itself! Perhaps I need to do as /revisions/1507645/3 directs...?

efibootmgr worked, though - it's been added. However, I don't see the entry in GRUB (although it would obviously be unbootable regardless). Is that expected?

That means your old EFI System Partition might have been deleted by Fedora's installer – so you should either point bcdboot at the EFI partition on the Fedora disk, or create a new EFI partition on the Windows disk, depending on how much effort you want to put into it. (If you used efibootmgr to directly add the \Windows\Boot\EFI\... files, I'd be surprised if those actually booted into an OS as-is...) GRUB doesn't use EFI boot entries; it's a completely separate thing (its menu is generated by grub-mkconfig and stored in grub.cfg).

@grawity, apologies for all the questions, but this really is new territory for me, so there shall be more. As an example: Considering that efibootmgr seemingly doesn't add entries to GRUB2, does that mean that I need to rebuild GRUB2 to have it add entries? I don't want to be running your commands and then wondering why they don't appear there. I suppose I should just use my UEFI's GUI to test, instead?

Additionally, can you clarify exactly how I should modify the commands you provided, since my Windows boot info appears to be entirely overwritten by Fedora's? I need this kind of hand-holding because I don't want to run potentially incorrect commands, considering how low-level this is. If you need any new information, just say, and I'll provide it. Thank you. Lots.

First of all you really need to decide whether you're trying to add entries to GRUB2 or whether you're trying to add entries to the UEFI menu. Even if those menus do roughly the same thing, they're still two different menus – shown by different software – whose entries come from very different sources. You asked about the UEFI GUI at first, so I answered primarily regarding the UEFI GUI, and that will have no effect on GRUB2's menu whatsoever (and vice versa).

@grawity, definitely EFI GUI (then I'll do GRUB2 when I can) because that's much less complexity. If you think those are worth separate questions, then I'll not unnecessarily expand the scope of this one. Apologies. I just want to know what commands to run now that I know that the original EFI file for Windows doesn't exist anymore.

Basically, my sole problem is finding the EFI volume to recreate the files inside. I've found https://superuser.com/q/1399789/904401, but list vol, which usually works for this, doesn't appear to list any "hidden" volumes.

The only one you have is nvme0n1p1 on the Fedora disk. You can either re-use that for Windows, or create a new one on the Windows disk (by shrinking one of the existing partitions by ~250 MB to make space).

Done it — all fixed! The problem was very strange — diskpart doesn't enumerate the hidden flag until I detail each part. Then, the flag displays in list vol. Many, many thanks for all your help. I've marked your answer as the solution, but shall publish my own later with exactly what I did, too.
